# Can't strip out _id from mongoose objects

Tags: nestjs

As per [nestjs doc page](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) I am using this code:

```
@Controller('books')
export class BooksController {

  constructor(
    private readonly bookService: BooksService,
  ) {}

  @SerializeOptions({
    excludePrefixes: ['_'],
  })
  @Get()
  async getAll(): Promise<Book[]> {
    return this.bookService.getAll();
  }
}
```

trying to strip `_id` (and presumably `__v` too) properties from the documents which are coming from mongodb/mongoose. Is there any other step I need to take to make it work? I have also tried placing the `@SerializeOptions` decorator over the `@Controller` - to no avail.

(It's only an exercise, IRL I would probably map *id*

Comment: Are you also using the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` exposed by NestJS? From the code sample, I'm not seeing the interceptor being bound.

Comment: Thanks Jay. In fact I have removed it carelessly while experimenting, but I think my other wrongdoing is that I am actually using an interface not a class. Which obviously cannot work as interface doesn't exist during runtime, but I needed it for `Model<Book>` and `book.save()` purposes. I am going to ask a more general question hoping the answers will give me a kick for understanding the concepts better.

Comment: Ah, yeah, you definitely need to be using a class for the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` to be able to strip out properties. You maybe be able to make a class that implements Model so that it can all work as you need to it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would love to hear your voice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881385/trying-to-understand-models-in-a-nestjs-mongoose-app if you have time :)